# MVC view not loading

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view

I have a Controller called ConfirmController.cs, in the Views folder I have a folder called Confirm which has a view called Payment.cshtml.

When a form is submitted a function on ConfirmController runs, saving a model to the DB.

Depending on a propery of the model it will either return the Payment view correctly as expected or it will Redirect to another url.

```
        if (!save.preview)
        {
            return this.View("Payment");
        }
        else
        {
            return this.Redirect(save.url);
        }
```

After redirecting to another url there is a button there which calls a function on ConfirmController which updates the model and works as expected.

After saving the model here it should return the view Payment, nothing changes in the browser but using breakpoints in VS I can see it goes through loading the page and in the dev console of the browser I can see the view is returned as a response.

Any ideas what I am missing here?

This is how the function to return the view Payment is called, this is when it doesnt change in the browser

```
         $.ajax({
         url: '../Confirm/ConfirmFromPreview',
         type: "POST",
         data: data
    })
```

Action Method signature:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ConfirmFromPreview(Occasions template) {}
```

This gets called fine and does everything as expected, im just not seeing the view change in the browser

Comment: Please provide the signature of you action method. Without it is very difficult to figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ajax call and You would be able to see this calling going in the browser developer tools network tab. Server would return someresponse to this call and as per your example this would be html in this case. But browser would not pick that html because it is not instructed to do so.
Nature of ajax is to call an endpoint on server to get some data (html in this case) in an asynchronous fashion. Then as a developer we need to write code that gets this data and update the browser DOM.

You may have to update the dom manually using Jquery for example. Something like:

$('#TargrtElementId').html("Response that is received from server");

Thus please keep the response in a variable and then update the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can't  display a view or  redirect this way using ajax.

To show a partial view change your action to

```
return PartialView("Payment"); 
//you can't return  Payment as a view since it will return a Layout too
```

and add to your ajax:

```
  success: function (result) {
                    $(div).html(result); // div - id of your div that contains 
                                          // your  Payment View
}
```

If you need to redirect you have to use a full url

```
return Redirect("http://www.myapp.com/save");
```

Or call your save method of the same controller directly (if you can or make save metod the way it  could be reached from several)  - return Save(model). The last line of your code should  return PartialView if you want to change your view.